# EWS Managed API 2.0 - Render CalendarView including all recurring appointments

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I do replicate from EWS using `.SyncFolderItems`. However, this does not include virtual items from recurring series. So I want in addition to render a calendar view for a specific range to get all those virtual items as well.

if I use

```
CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(start, end, 1000);
FindItemsResults<Appointment> findAppointmentResults = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);
```

does EWS returns all appointments in this range including the virtual appointments from recurring-series? Or do I have to go the hard way described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633700(v=exchg.80).aspx) and enumerate manually to all items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will run into the same situation. I tried and already succeeded in render both types of appointments.

EWS API calendar view automatically renders a recurring series for you.

The interesting part is how to set a approach that make it possible to replicate and also update your database in case the series gets deleted.

1. Sync your appointments using `SyncFolderItems`
2. Store `AppointmentType` (Single, ReccuringMaster, Occurrence, Exception) in your database.
3. Store `Id.UniqueId` for each appointment in your database
4. Store `cleanGlobalObjectId` as well! How to get it:

   ```
   var cleanGlobalObjectId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Meeting, 0x23, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
   var psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { cleanGlobalObjectId };
   object calIdVal;
   ewsAppointment.TryGetProperty(cleanGlobalObjectId, out calIdVal);
   var syncId = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])calIdVal);
   ```
5. To delete all appointments in your database you can use `syncId` you get in 3. to catch them all. Example: If the `RecurringMaster` is deleted by user. Delete all rows that refers to it.
6. After you synchronized appointments you can render a view from for a specific range to replicate those virtual appointments into your database. Easiest approach imho is to remove all by `syncId` and insert all again.

   ```
   var calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(informerAccountMailbox.Mailbox)), psPropSet);
   var cView = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now.AddDays(informerAccountMailbox.DaysBeforeNow*-1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(informerAccountMailbox.DaysFromNow), 1000);
   var appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);
   ```

Hope this helps.